# Every parent controller must have `get{SINGULAR}Action($id)` method when i have multi level sub resource in FOS Rest Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.7

I have three controller named `BlogController`, `PostController`, `CommentController` that `CommentController` is sub resource of `PostController` and `PostController` sub resource of `BlogController`.

```
/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("blog", pluralize=false)
 */
class BlogController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($blogUri)
    {
    ...
    }
}

/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("post", pluralize=false)
 */
class PostController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($postId)
    {
    ...
    }
}

/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("comment", pluralize=false)
 */
class CommentController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($commentId)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

routing.yml

```
mgh_blog:
    resource: MGH\BlogBundle\Controller\BlogController
    type:     rest

mgh_blog_post:
    resource: MGH\BlogBundle\Controller\PostController
    type:     rest
    parent:   mgh_blog

mgh_blog_post_comment:
    resource: MGH\PostBundle\Controller\CommentController
    type:     rest
    parent:   mgh_blog_post
```

I define `getAction` methods, but i get following error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  Every parent controller must have `get{SINGULAR}Action($id)` method  
  where {SINGULAR} is a singular form of associated object
```

---

Edit:

I also try to change the method's name to `getCommentAction($commentId)`, `getPostAction($postId)` and `getBlogAction`, but it no work.

When I use `@RouteResource` annotations, method name must be `getAction($id)`, otherwise it doesn't work.

**When I change parent of `mgh_blog_post_comment` router to `mgh_blog`, it's working!**

Comment: Can you please post the output of the command `app/console debug:router`?

Comment: @giosh94mhz `debug:router` dump `InvalidArgumentException` error

Comment: That's the same error you get on the webserver. You need to comment out the offending route, then run the command. This way, I can see which route may interfere (if any)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error description is awful and a big time waster because it doesn't tell you what the real problem is. Try the following:

```
/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("blog", pluralize=false)
 */
class BlogController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($blogUri)
    {
    ...
    }
}

/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("post", pluralize=false)
 */
class PostController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($blogUri, $postId)
    {
    ...
    }
}

/**
 * @Rest\RouteResource("comment", pluralize=false)
 */
class CommentController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getAction($blogUri, $postId, $commentId)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

You didn't have the correct number of arguments in the descendant controller actions. It took me two days of step debugging to figure this out.

The parent route, Blog, looks like:

```
/blog/{blogUri}
```

It will match

```
public function getAction($blogUri)
```

The child route, Post, looks like:

```
/blog/{blogUri}/post/{postId}
```

It will **not** match the code below because it needs two parameters. The same is true for the grandchild--which is looking for three parameters:

```
public function getAction($postId)
```

The grandchild route, Comment, looks like:

```
/blog/{blogUri}/post/{postId}/comment/{commentId}
```

The code keeps track of the ancestors of each controller.
The post has 1 ancestor. When building the routes for the post controller, the code looks at the number of parameters on the 'get action'. It take the number of parameters and subtracts the number of ancestors. If the difference is not equal to one, it throws the error.

Conclusion, for each descendant, it needs to include the ID parameters of it ancestors AND its own ID. There should always be one more parameter than there are ancestors.

Comment: I know how you feel. I figured it out after taking 2 days combing through the code. I plan to write a better error description and do a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?:

```
class CommentController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function getCommentAction($commentId)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The issues is the number of arguments in the singular get action of the descendant controllers. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public function cgetAction(Request $request)
{
    ...
}
```

This is my controller example:

```
<?php

namespace Cf\SClinicBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use Cf\SClinicBundle\Entity\CfAcquireImage;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException as DBALException;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException as NoResultException;

/**
 * CfAcquireImage controller.
 *
 * @RouteResource("acquire-image")
 */
class ApiCfAcquireImageController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $status;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $parameter;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $role_name;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Lists all Cf Acquire Image entities.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function cgetAction(Request $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Finds a Cf Acquire Image entity by id.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param         $id $id
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Create a new Cf Acquire Image entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function postAction(Request $request)
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param         $id
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function putAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Cf Acquire Image entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param         $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i have `cgetAction` method, this problem is not from `cgetAction` as i say in question, that need `get{SINGULAR}Action($id)` method

Comment: The singular is only:     
 public function getAction(Request $request, $id)
    {

    }

Comment: thank for help, I defined this method, i think fos can not handle multi level sub resource

Comment: @ghanbari It can handle multilevel ancestry. The issues is the number of arguements. See my answer for details.